# PHP foreach - parsed json from URL

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have a JSON file called from an URL. I've checked and I'm getting the the data from the URL.
I've tried a lot, but I can't get the loop `foreach` to work - what is wrong?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://banen.klintmx.dk/json/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=api.autoit.dk/car/GetCarsExtended/59efc61e-ceb2-463b-af39-80348d771999';
$json= file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($json);
$rows = $data->{'contents'};
foreach($rows as $row) {
echo '<p>';
$FabrikatNavn = $row->{'contents'}->{'FabrikatNavn'};
$ModelNavn = $row->{'contents'}->{'ModelNavn'};
$PrisDetailDkk = $row->{'contents'}->{'PrisDetailDkk'};
echo $FabrikatNavn . $ModelNavn . ' Pris ' . $PrisDetailDkk;
echo '</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: I've never seen a notation like this `$data->{'contents'}` in PHP. What is the error message?

Comment: You can replace `$data->{'contents'}` with `$data->contents`. The syntax is used, if you want to access dynamic properties, like `$data->{$otherVar}`

Comment: @bali182 - That will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is you trying to access `content` object again. Just change your foreach snippet with,

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<p>';
    $FabrikatNavn = $row->FabrikatNavn;
    $ModelNavn = $row->ModelNavn;
    $PrisDetailDkk = $row->PrisDetailDkk;
    echo $FabrikatNavn . $ModelNavn . ' Pris ' . $PrisDetailDkk;
    echo '</p>';
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tCS9as)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode($data, true)` so that it parses the JSON content into a PHP array. So it will be something like

```
$rows = $data['contents'];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<p>';
    $FabrikatNavn = $row['contents']['FabrikatNavn'];
    $ModelNavn = $row['contents']['ModelNavn'];
    $PrisDetailDkk = $row['contents']['PrisDetailDkk'];
    echo $FabrikatNavn . $ModelNavn . ' Pris ' . $PrisDetailDkk;
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: `json_decode($contents, true)` does what you said. otherwise the associative parts will be objects.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know that. I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using `json_decode($json, true)` as this will convert the data to an associative array which seems to be the way you are approaching the solution.

Check the output by printing with `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$data = json_decode($json,true); //decode json result as array and thenloop it
print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
foreach($data as $row){
//do something here
}
```